# Ubuntu 16.04 libmfhdfalt.so.0 is missing

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I tried both install Mysql Workbench using .deb package and apt. Always returns the same error when launching it.

I tried uninstall and install it again back and forth and the same error occurred. First I try to run Mysql Workbench using launcher, the icon pop in the launcher and after few seconds, it close. Then I tried to run

```
mysql-workbench
```

on console then I discovered this error.

```
/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin: error while loading shared libraries: libmfhdfalt.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried to list library using this command

```
sudo ls /usr/lib/
```

Couldn’t find any library match that name, is there really library libmfhdfalt exist? because I couldn’t find the it anywhere on the Net except this

https://www.apt-browse.org/browse/debian/wheezy/main/i386/libhdf4-0-alt/4.2r4-13/file/usr/lib/libmfhdfalt.so.0

Edit 1:
Ran

```
ldd /usr/lib/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin
```

Result

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd7d3f5000)
libsqlide.so.6.3.6 => /usr/lib/mysql-workbench/libsqlide.so.6.3.6 (0x00007ff853b2b000)
libwbprivate.so.6.3.6 => /usr/lib/mysql-workbench/libwbprivate.so.6.3.6 (0x00007ff852f99000)
libwbpublic.so.6.3.6 => /usr/lib/mysql-workbench/libwbpublic.so.6.3.6 (0x00007ff85222b000)
libgrt.so.6.3.6 => /usr/lib/mysql-workbench/libgrt.so.6.3.6 (0x00007ff851f27000)
libcdbc.so.6.3.6 => /usr/lib/mysql-workbench/libcdbc.so.6.3.6 (0x00007ff851d0c000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007ff8519b2000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007ff8516a1000)
libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007ff85144e000)
libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007ff851249000)
libcairo.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2 (0x00007ff850f35000)
libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0x00007ff850c80000)
libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0x00007ff850634000)
libsigc-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsigc-2.0.so.0 (0x00007ff85042e000)
libglibmm-2.4.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglibmm-2.4.so.1 (0x00007ff8501b5000)
libatkmm-1.6.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatkmm-1.6.so.1 (0x00007ff84ff6a000)
libgdkmm-2.4.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdkmm-2.4.so.1 (0x00007ff84fd1d000)
libgtkmm-2.4.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtkmm-2.4.so.1 (0x00007ff84f6fa000)
libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007ff84f16b000)
libgnome-keyring.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so.0 (0x00007ff84ef45000)
libmforms.so.6.3.6 => /usr/lib/mysql-workbench/libmforms.so.6.3.6 (0x00007ff84ea4f000)
liblinux_utilities.so.6.3.6 => /usr/lib/mysql-workbench/liblinux_utilities.so.6.3.6 (0x00007ff84e7ee000)
libmdcanvasgtk.so.6.3.6 => /usr/lib/mysql-workbench/libmdcanvasgtk.so.6.3.6 (0x00007ff84e5c5000)
libwbbase.so.6.3.6 => /usr/lib/mysql-workbench/libwbbase.so.6.3.6 (0x00007ff84e37d000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007ff84dffa000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007ff84dcf1000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007ff84dadb000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff84d710000)
libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 (0x00007ff84d4ee000)
libpangomm-1.4.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangomm-1.4.so.1 (0x00007ff84d2c1000)
libmdcanvas.so.6.3.6 => /usr/lib/mysql-workbench/libmdcanvas.so.6.3.6 (0x00007ff84cfd7000)
libzip.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzip.so.4 (0x00007ff84cdc4000)
libtinyxml.so.2.6.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinyxml.so.2.6.2 (0x00007ff84cbae000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007ff84c93d000)
libpcrecpp.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcrecpp.so.0 (0x00007ff84c734000)
libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007ff84c379000)
libvsqlitepp.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvsqlitepp.so.3 (0x00007ff84c154000)
libmysqlparser.so.6.3.6 => /usr/lib/mysql-workbench/libmysqlparser.so.6.3.6 (0x00007ff8497fe000)
libctemplate.so.2 => /usr/lib/libctemplate.so.2 (0x00007ff84959e000)
libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/nvidia-384/libGL.so.1 (0x00007ff8492f9000)
libgdal.so.1 => /usr/lib/libgdal.so.1 (0x00007ff8484c5000)
libantlr3c_wb.so => /usr/lib/mysql-workbench/libantlr3c_wb.so (0x00007ff8482a9000)
libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007ff8480a3000)
libmysqlcppconn.so.7 => /usr/lib/libmysqlcppconn.so.7 (0x00007ff847d80000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007ff847b5e000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ff847959000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ff84773c000)
libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007ff847534000)
libpixman-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x00007ff84728b000)
libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007ff847048000)
libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007ff846d9e000)
libpng12.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0x00007ff846b78000)
libxcb-shm.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0x00007ff846974000)
libxcb-render.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-render.so.0 (0x00007ff84676a000)
libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007ff84655f000)
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007ff84634d000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007ff846133000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007ff845f2a000)
libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 (0x00007ff845d1d000)
libpango-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0 (0x00007ff845ad1000)
libgio-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0x00007ff845748000)
libXinerama.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1 (0x00007ff845545000)
libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0x00007ff845335000)
libXrandr.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2 (0x00007ff845129000)
libXcursor.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1 (0x00007ff844f1f000)
libXcomposite.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcomposite.so.1 (0x00007ff844d1c000)
libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007ff844b18000)
libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007ff844912000)
libatk-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so.0 (0x00007ff8446ec000)
libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 (0x00007ff8444d6000)
libcairomm-1.0.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairomm-1.0.so.1 (0x00007ff8442b2000)
libgiomm-2.4.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgiomm-2.4.so.1 (0x00007ff843f0d000)
libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007ff843d0a000)
libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007ff843abd000)
libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007ff8437dc000)
libwbscintilla.so => /usr/lib/mysql-workbench/libwbscintilla.so (0x00007ff8434fd000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00005631683fa000)
libicuuc.so.55 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55 (0x00007ff843168000)
liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007ff842f45000)
libsqlite3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0 (0x00007ff842c70000)
libGLX.so.0 => /usr/lib/nvidia-384/libGLX.so.0 (0x00007ff842a3f000)
libGLdispatch.so.0 => /usr/lib/nvidia-384/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0x00007ff842771000)
libarmadillo.so.6 => /usr/lib/libarmadillo.so.6 (0x00007ff842569000)
libproj.so.9 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproj.so.9 (0x00007ff84230d000)
libpoppler.so.58 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpoppler.so.58 (0x00007ff841e8f000)
libfreexl.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreexl.so.1 (0x00007ff841c86000)
libgeos_c.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgeos_c.so.1 (0x00007ff841a57000)
libwebp.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so.5 (0x00007ff8417fb000)
libepsilon.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libepsilon.so.1 (0x00007ff8415e3000)
libodbc.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbc.so.2 (0x00007ff841379000)
libodbcinst.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbcinst.so.2 (0x00007ff841167000)
libkmlbase.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkmlbase.so.1 (0x00007ff840f4d000)
libkmldom.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkmldom.so.1 (0x00007ff840c93000)
libkmlengine.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkmlengine.so.1 (0x00007ff840a59000)
libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007ff840830000)
libxerces-c-3.1.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxerces-c-3.1.so (0x00007ff8402ba000)
libopenjp2.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenjp2.so.7 (0x00007ff840083000)
libjasper.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjasper.so.1 (0x00007ff83fe2e000)
libnetcdf.so.11 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdf.so.11 (0x00007ff83caca000)
libhdf5_serial.so.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_serial.so.10 (0x00007ff83c62d000)
libmfhdfalt.so.0 => not found
libdfalt.so.0 => not found
libogdi.so.3.2 => /usr/lib/libogdi.so.3.2 (0x00007ff83c40b000)
libgif.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgif.so.7 (0x00007ff83c202000)
libjpeg.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8 (0x00007ff83bfa8000)
libpq.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5 (0x00007ff83bd78000)
libdapclient.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdapclient.so.6 (0x00007ff83bb39000)
libdap.so.17 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdap.so.17 (0x00007ff83b7ba000)
libspatialite.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libspatialite.so.7 (0x00007ff83b037000)
libcurl-gnutls.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4 (0x00007ff83adca000)
libmysqlclient.so.20 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.20 (0x00007ff83a7b9000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007ff83a5b5000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007ff83a3ae000)
libthai.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthai.so.0 (0x00007ff83a1a5000)
libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007ff839f82000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007ff839d67000)
libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007ff839b08000)
libsystemd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0 (0x00007ff839a83000)
libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007ff83986e000)
libicudata.so.55 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.55 (0x00007ff837db7000)
libblas.so.3 => /usr/lib/libblas.so.3 (0x00007ff837b47000)
liblapack.so.3 => /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3 (0x00007ff83734f000)
libarpack.so.2 => /usr/lib/libarpack.so.2 (0x00007ff837104000)
libsuperlu.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsuperlu.so.4 (0x00007ff836e97000)
liblcms2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblcms2.so.2 (0x00007ff836c40000)
libtiff.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5 (0x00007ff8369cc000)
libgeos-3.5.0.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgeos-3.5.0.so (0x00007ff836631000)
libltdl.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7 (0x00007ff836427000)
libminizip.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libminizip.so.1 (0x00007ff83621b000)
liburiparser.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liburiparser.so.1 (0x00007ff836000000)
libhdf5_serial_hl.so.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_serial_hl.so.10 (0x00007ff835ddf000)
libsz.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsz.so.2 (0x00007ff835bdc000)
libssl.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007ff835972000)
libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007ff83552e000)
libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007ff8352e4000)
libldap_r-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap_r-2.4.so.2 (0x00007ff835092000)
libidn.so.11 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11 (0x00007ff834e5f000)
librtmp.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librtmp.so.1 (0x00007ff834c42000)
libnettle.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.6 (0x00007ff834a0c000)
libgnutls.so.30 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30 (0x00007ff8346dc000)
liblber-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblber-2.4.so.2 (0x00007ff8344cc000)
libdatrie.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdatrie.so.1 (0x00007ff8342c4000)
libgraphite2.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007ff83409d000)
libgfortran.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3 (0x00007ff833d72000)
libjbig.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjbig.so.0 (0x00007ff833b63000)
libaec.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaec.so.0 (0x00007ff83395b000)
libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007ff833688000)
libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007ff833459000)
libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007ff833255000)
libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007ff833049000)
libsasl2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2 (0x00007ff832e2e000)
libgssapi.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi.so.3 (0x00007ff832bed000)
libhogweed.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.4 (0x00007ff8329b9000)
libgmp.so.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007ff832739000)
libp11-kit.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0 (0x00007ff8324d5000)
libtasn1.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6 (0x00007ff8322c1000)
libquadmath.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libquadmath.so.0 (0x00007ff832082000)
libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007ff831e7d000)
libheimntlm.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimntlm.so.0 (0x00007ff831c74000)
libkrb5.so.26 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.26 (0x00007ff8319e9000)
libasn1.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasn1.so.8 (0x00007ff831747000)
libhcrypto.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhcrypto.so.4 (0x00007ff831514000)
libroken.so.18 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libroken.so.18 (0x00007ff8312fd000)
libwind.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwind.so.0 (0x00007ff8310d4000)
libheimbase.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimbase.so.1 (0x00007ff830ec4000)
libhx509.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhx509.so.5 (0x00007ff830c79000)
libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007ff830a41000)
```

Edit 2:

```
sanik@sanik-ubuntu:~$ dpkg -L libhdf4-0-alt
Package 'libhdf4-0-alt' does not contain any files (!)
sanik@sanik-ubuntu:~$ sudo ls -l /usr/lib/lib*dfalt.so*
ls: cannot access '/usr/lib/lib*dfalt.so*': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to show the output of `ldd /usr/lib/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin`?

Comment: it seems two library are missing, libmfhdfalt and libdfalt

Comment: They are both part of `libhdf4-0-alt`; what do `dpkg -L libhdf4-0-alt` and `ls -l /usr/lib/lib*dfalt.so*` produce?

Comment: added for edit 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `libhdf4-0-alt` package is somehow broken.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libhdf4-0-alt
```

should fix that.

Comment: brilliant, thank you Mr. Kitt, now issue resolved, phew... I'm thinking that maybe I just wait for Ubuntu 18.04 and install new OS, haha

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file && sudo apt-file update
```

Now you can search for the missing library.

```
apt-file search libmfhdfalt.so.0
```

It will show you which package contains the missing library and you can install it.

It is always a good idea too, when you install a single package to execute

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

afterwards.

Comment: ran this
apt-file search libmfhdfalt.so.0
and I got this
libhdf4-0-alt: /usr/lib/libmfhdfalt.so.0
libhdf4-0-alt: /usr/lib/libmfhdfalt.so.0.0.0
uninstall mysql-workbench, install it again, same error missing libmfhdfalt.so.0 still occurs

Comment: Did you try installing `libhdf4-0-alt`?

Comment: @Bahamut regarding `apt-get -f install`, it’s an even better idea to avoid breaking the installation in the first place, *e.g.* by using `gdebi` or `apt install` to install `.deb` files instead of `dpkg -i`.

Comment: **libhdf4-0-alt is already the newest version (4.2.10-3.2)** tried `apt-get -f install` and still same

Comment: Can you show `sudo grep libmfhdfalt.so.0 /etc/ld.so.cache`

Comment: I ran that and no result

Comment: @Nik Saiful Anuar. I oversee that your problem is solved. Nevermind